# What day of the week does the Stellar network pay out inflation?

Tags: inflation, lumens

From the [Stellar Developer Guide](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/inflation.html):

> Each week, the protocol distributes these lumens to any account that
>   gets over .05% of the “votes” from other accounts in the network.

What day of the week (and at what time) do these inflation payouts occur?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inflation occurs when both of the following conditions occur:

- Someone (and it can be anyone) sends a transaction with [`inflation`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#inflation) operation.
- *It's time* to run inflation.

The inflation round is computed as number of weeks since July 1st, 2014. So users can run inflation for the current round and all the previous rounds (if `inflation` operation was not sent during the previous round).

If it's not time to run inflation the Stellar network will return `INFLATION_NOT_TIME` error.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question.  What day/time is inflation currently running at?  It's Monday, but not sure what time.  It doesn't ask when it's valid to be generated, but when is it currently generated.

Comment: @Zach it happens when: "Someone (and it can be anyone) sends a transaction with inflation operation." So the day and hour is unknown but usually someone submits it as soon as it's possible.

Comment: Are we able to confirm this is UTC time? I know most dates are unix timestamped, but if I wanted a CRON expression to capture the coming week's inflation transaction would i start looking at roughly
00:00:00 UTC on Tuesdays? (or slightly before)

I'm wanting to run a stream that awaits the transaction but I want to minimize the uptime.

Comment: @Jarret you can't predict it for 100% however given that we have a few inflation pools right now people want to submit `inflation` operation as fast as possible. So currently it will be almost exactly a week after the last one. You can check my answer here to find out how to find it: https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/279/33

Comment: @Bartek I was going of the assumption that the inflation order would be submitted instantly, or at least within a minute or 2. My original plan was to use the second method shown there to get the date of the last inflation, and then set up a weekly function that will open and read from a stream within a reasonable margin of 1 week from that time and look for the inflation transaction. I was just looking to narrow that margin to be as accurate as possible but I think this is good enough for now, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It depends on when somebody initiates it. From the same page you linked to:

> Inflation is run in response to an inflation operation that anyone can submit to the network. This operation will fail if the inflation sequence number isn’t one after the last sequence number. It will also fail if (sequence number * 1 week) of time hasn’t elapsed since the network start date.

Answer (score 3):

12am UTC on Tuesdays every week.

The other answers tell you how it works, but I felt it necessary to answer the actual question, of "What day of the week" by actually looking historically.

To properly answer your question, I had to do some digging in my related question: [How can I determine when the last inflation was distributed?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/186/how-can-i-determine-when-the-last-inflation-was-distributed/)

I've gone back multiple inflation periods in the past couple months and they all have paid out at 12am UTC Tuesdays.  For those in the US, that's Monday evening.

As of posting, the most recent inflation operations:

https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/67968810941947905

https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/67291155296956417

https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/66694601519403009

You'll notice that they've all been submitted by the same wallet, so it's safe to assume that the day/time will stay consistent for the foreseeable future.