# How to access the "All Operations" Horizon endpoint using the Go SDK?

Tags: horizon, go-sdk

I'm working on an inflation pool, using the go SDK. However the client/horizon package doesn't expose all the horizon endpoints (the Client Interface only has Root, HomeDomainForAccount, LoadAccount, LoadAccountOffers, LoadMemo, LoadOrderBook, StreamLedgers, StreamPayment, StreamTransaction,  and SubmitTransaction).

For example, if I want to detect the last inflation operation validated, using JavaScript I could follow the suggestions from here: [How can I determine when the last inflation was distributed?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/186/how-can-i-determine-when-the-last-inflation-was-distributed/279)

But using the Go SDK doesn't seem to be that simple. I even tried importing the `services/horizon/internal/resourceadapter/operations` [package](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon/internal/resourceadapter/operations/main.go), since it already has the struct definitions for the operations returned by the Horizon Endpoint. But Go doesn't allow that, with the error "use of internal package not allowed".

Is this a design decision of the Go SDK? Is JavaScript the best way to access these Horizon Endpoints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The horizon `internal` package is not the right ones to use. It implements the **server side**. Like the [js-stellar-sdk](https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-sdk) you will need to do an [**api call**](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/operations-all.html) to horizon:

`curl "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/operations?limit=200&order=desc"`

The `clients/horizon` package is the client library for Go with helper methods.

**Edit**

There is no support for the operations method in the horizon client (yet). But it's not complicated to do. See my example below:

**Last time inflation distributed**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/stellar/go/clients/horizon"
)

type Operations struct {
    Links struct {
        Self horizon.Link `json:"self"`
        Next horizon.Link `json:"next"`
        Prev horizon.Link `json:"prev"`
    } `json:"_links"`
    Embedded struct {
        Records []Operation `json:"records"`
    } `json:"_embedded"`
}

type Operation struct {
    ID          string    `json:"id"`
    Type        string    `json:"type"`
    PagingToken string    `json:"paging_token"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"created_at"`
}

func main() {
    operationsURL := "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/operations?limit=200&order=desc"
    for operationsURL != "" {
        log.Print("calling: ", operationsURL)
        resp, err := http.Get(operationsURL)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to fetch operations from horizon: %s", err)
        }
        var operations Operations
        if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&operations); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to decode operations: %s", err)
        }
        for _, o := range operations.Embedded.Records {
            if o.Type == "inflation" {
                log.Printf("Last inflation distributed at %s (%s})", o.CreatedAt, o.ID)
                os.Exit(0)
            }
        }
        operationsURL = operations.Links.Next.Href
    }
    log.Fatalf("not found")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `clients/horizon` package implements some of the endpoints (and defines some of the [responses structs](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/clients/horizon/responses.go)), but not all of them, hence my question if this is a design decision. For example, you can just call `client.LoadAccount(id)` instead of `curl "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/<id>"`.

Comment: The internal package was introduced when horizon was moved to the monorepo: see https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/126